# C# - ModalPopupExtender opened by DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, modalpopupextender

While finding similar questions, I have not found an answer that gets me where I am trying to go.

I have a ModalPopupExtender that I have linked to a DropDownList populated with Job #s. When I select a Job from the list, I want the panel to appear.  This does not happen, however, if I click the dropdown a 2nd time (after having selected a job) the Panel becomes visible as expected, with the data populated.

Here is the relevant code in the aspx:

```
<Ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="NonImportedPopupExtender" runat="server"  
    OkControlID="ImportButton"
    TargetControlID="NonImportedDetailDropDownList" 
    CancelControlID="CancelButton" 
    OnCancelScript="PopupCancel()" 
    OnOkScript="NonImportedModalPopupDoUpdate()"
    PopupControlID="NonImportedPopupPanel" />
<asp:Panel ID="NonImportedPopupPanel" runat="server" Width="600" Height="350">
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="NotImportedLabel" runat="server" Text="NonImported Job Detail:"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Repeater ID="NonImportedDetailRepeater" runat="server"
    >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table width="450">
                <tr>
                    <th>TSID</th>
                    <th>PKey</th>
                    <th>EID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>ST Hrs</th>
                    <th>OT Hrs</th>
                    <th>BIT</th>
                    <th>Vision</th>
                    <th>Imported</th>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Eval("TimesheetID") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("PKey") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Employee") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("RegHrs") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("OvtHrs") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("BIT_Directive") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("VisionStatus") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Completed") %></td>
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:Button ID="ImportButton" runat="server" Text="Set As Imported" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Visible="false" />
</asp:Panel>
```

And here is the index change for the dropdownlist:

```
protected void NonImportedDetailDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string myJob = this.NonImportedDetailDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();
        NonImportedPopupPanel.Visible = true;

        if (myJob != null)
        {

            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InterfaceDev"].ConnectionString);
            string myCommandText = "BillingDirectives_ShowNonImportedByJob";
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myCommandText, myConn);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job", myJob);
            SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
            DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
            NonImportedDetailRepeater.DataSource = myDataTable;
            NonImportedDetailRepeater.DataBind();
            CancelButton.Visible = true;
            ImportButton.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            WarningLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            WarningLabel.Text = "Cannot determine selected Job #!";
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        WarningLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        WarningLabel.Text = "SQL Error: " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Here is the DDL - Adam's question below:

```
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="NonImportedLabel" runat="server" Text="Show NonImported Detail:"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="NonImportedDetailDropDownList" runat="server" 
            Width="140" 
            ToolTip="Show NonImported Detail by Job"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="NonImportedDetailDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoPostBack="True">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see NonImportedDetailDropDownList in the aspx markup code.  Is it set to do a post back?

Comment: Adam, I will add that to the question above.  It is a rather large page, so I did not include everything.  Thanks for asking, and yes, the postback is true.

Comment: GOT IT!!  Add this line to the SelectedIndexChanged event -

NonImportedPopupExtender.Show();